# Write logs from .NET Core WebAPI to mongodb?

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core, ms.extensions.logging

I am developing a web app and i need a way to write logs into mongodb. I had setup  mongo already and work with db for some time without any problems.I have done some research but from all of libraries on NuGet, neither one fits my needs.

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to write logs, I've used NLog and so on, but now i need that next step to write all of that in database on runtime. Is it possible that either of these libs does not support .NET Core for saving logs in mongo?

Anyone with the same problem/experience?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use mongo target from this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.MongoDB.NetCore/1.0.0

Comment: i have already, doesn't work for me...